# Creating a Google Drive repository with service account mail

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a Google Drive folder with a service account. A folder seems to be created but when I'm going into my Drive I can't see it. When I'm searching with the URL with the folder id I have a page with this message 'Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.'.
I can't clearly identify the problem, is it due to the fact that my email and the email for the service account are not the same ?

Here's my currents functions :

```
credentials_file = 'sa-sheet-creation.json'
scope_drive = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds_drive = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(credentials_file, scope_drive)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds_drive)

def get_drive_folder_id(target_email):
    # Obtenez l'ID du dossier "My Drive" du destinataire (adresse e-mail)
    results = drive_service.files().list(q=f"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false and '{target_email}' in owners",fields="files(id, name)").execute()
    folders = results.get('files', [])
    if folders:
        for folder in folders:
            if folder['name'] == 'My Drive':
                return folder['id']
    return None

def create_folder_google_drive(respository_mail, target_email):
    
    metadata = {
        'name': respository_mail,
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    }
    folder_id = get_drive_folder_id(target_email)
    if folder_id:
        metadata['parents'] = [folder_id]
    
    created_file = drive_service.files().create(body=metadata, fields='id').execute()
    return dossier_cree['id']
```

Comment: are you getting an error message ?  if so what is it ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- It seems that in your showing script, `dossier_cree` is not declared. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script.
- I supposes that `return dossier_cree['id']` is modified to `return created_file['id']`. Under this condition, when I saw your script, when the owner of `return folder['id']` is your Google account, you can see the created folder by the service account in your folder. But, you say `A folder seems to be created but when I'm going into my Drive I can't see it.`. From this situation, I'm worried that in this case, the folder might be created to the root folder of the Google Drive of the service account because the folder of your Google account was not found.
- In your situation, a folder is created using a service account. And, from `A folder seems to be created but when I'm going into my Drive I can't see it.`, I guess that you want to find the created folder in your Google Drive. In this case, your consideration of `is it due to the fact that my email and the email for the service account are not the same ?` is correct. The Google Drive of the service account is different from your Google Drive. By this, the folder created by the service account cannot be found in your Google Drive.

In order to find the folder created by the service account in your Google Drive using your script, as a simple method, how about the following flow?

#### Sample flow:

1. Create a new folder in your Google Drive with a sample name of "sample folder".
2. Share this folder with the email of the service account as the editor.
3. Modify your script as follows.

   - From

     ```
       if folder['name'] == 'My Drive':
     ```
   - To

     ```
       if folder['name'] == 'sample folder':
     ```
4. Run your script.

By this flow, a new folder is created in the folder in your Google account with the service account. You can find the created folder in your Google Drive.